# Parsing nested JSON in go language

Tags: go

How could I parse and extract certain values from below JSON

Here is the sample JSON response

```
{
   "success":true,
   "endpoint":"https://api.abcxyz.com",
   "info":{
      "Guestconnected":134,
      "Guestratio":100000.06963,
      "symbol1":{
         "code":"NY",
         "symbol":"*",
         "name":"newyear",
         "codev":391.78161,
         "symbolAppearsAfter":false,
         "local":true
      },
      "symbol2":{
         "code":"HNY",
         "symbol":"@",
         "name":"HappyNewYear",
         "codev":1000000.0960,
         "symbolAppearsAfter":true,
         "local":false
      },
      "latest":{
         "value":1597509,
         "autovalue":"00099cf8da58a36c08f2ef98650ff6043ddfb",
         "height":474696,
         "time":1499527696
      }
   },
   "Allguest":{
      "all":4,
      "filtered":4,
      "total_invitations":15430,
      "sent_invitations":15430,
      "final_invitations":0
   },
   "Guestlist":[
      {
         "GuestCode":"369AR",
         "all":2,
         "total_invitations":5430,
         "sent_invitations":5430,
         "final_invitations":0,
         "change":0,
         "accounts":0
      },
      {
         "GuestCode":"6POIA96TY",
         "all":2,
         "total_invitations":10000,
         "sent_invitations":10000,
         "final_invitations":0,
         "change":0,
         "accounts":0
      }
   ]
}
```

My Code is :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)


type object struct {
    Success bool `json:"success"`
    Endpoint string `json:"endpoint"`
    Allguest struct {
        All int `json:"all"`
        Filtered int `json:"filtered"`
        TotalInvitations int `json:"total_invitations"`
        SentInvitations int `json:"sent_invitations"`
        FinalInvitations int `json:"final_invitations"`
    } `json:"Allguest"`
    Guestlist []struct {
        GuestCode string `json:"GuestCode"`
        All int `json:"all"`
        TotalInvitations int `json:"total_invitations"`
        SentInvitations int `json:"sent_invitations"`
        FinalInvitations int `json:"final_invitations"`
        Change int `json:"change"`
        Accounts int `json:"accounts"`
    } `json:"Guestlist"`
}

func main() {

uri := "https://siteurl.com/api?lists=1"
res, err := http.Get(uri)
fmt.Println(uri)
if err != nil {
fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer res.Body.Close()

 var s object
err := json.NewDecoder(res.Body).Decode(&s)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
}
fmt.Println(s.Success)
fmt.Println(s.Allguest.TotalInvitations)
for i := 0; i < 6; i++ {
fmt.Println(s.Guestlist[i].TotalInvitations)
)

}
```

The problem is :

1. If the response is null it is giving `index out of range error` how can we avoid this ?
2. Applying condition if `TotalInvitations` value is greater than `100` then save in `100.csv` else save in `others.csv`

Answer (score 1):

If you need only certain entries from JSON you can define a structure with only those fields you are interested in. And if value can be null it is better to declare a pointer in the structure. Please take a look at an example at go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/mEwSXvPg3D

Answer (score 0):

use [gjson](https://github.com/tidwall/gjson) pkg to get value from json document an simple way

example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/tidwall/gjson"
)

func main() {
    data := []byte(`{
   "success": true,
   "endpoint": "https://api.abcxyz.com",
   "info": {
      "Guestconnected": 134,
      "Guestratio": 100000.06963,
      "symbol1": {
         "code": "NY",
         "symbol": "*",
         "name": "newyear",
         "codev": 391.78161,
         "symbolAppearsAfter": false,
         "local": true
      },
      "symbol2": {
         "code": "HNY",
         "symbol": "@",
         "name": "HappyNewYear",
         "codev": 1000000.096,
         "symbolAppearsAfter": true,
         "local": false
      },
      "latest": {
         "value": 1597509,
         "autovalue": "00099cf8da58a36c08f2ef98650ff6043ddfb",
         "height": 474696,
         "time": 1499527696
      }
   },
   "Allguest": {
      "all": 4,
      "filtered": 4,
      "total_invitations": 15430,
      "sent_invitations": 15430,
      "final_invitations": 0
   },
   "Guestlist": [
      {
         "GuestCode": "369AR",
         "all": 2,
         "total_invitations": 5430,
         "sent_invitations": 5430,
         "final_invitations": 0,
         "change": 0,
         "accounts": 0
      },
      {
         "GuestCode": "6POIA96TY",
         "all": 2,
         "total_invitations": 10000,
         "sent_invitations": 10000,
         "final_invitations": 0,
         "change": 0,
         "accounts": 0
      }
   ]
    }
    `)

    r := gjson.GetBytes(data, "Allguest.total_invitations")
    fmt.Println(r.Value()) // output 15430

    r = gjson.GetBytes(data, "Guestlist.#.total_invitations")
    fmt.Println(r.Value()) // output [5430 10000]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. > If the response is null it is giving index out of range error how can
   >   we avoid this?

   Unless I'm misunderstanding you, the response being null shouldn't matter.  If you receive 2 Guestlist items, you can only loop over those 2, meaning `for i := 0; i < 6; i++` is wrong.  Change it to `for i := 0; i < len(s.Guestlist); i++` or `for i := range s.Guestlist`.
2. > Applying condition if TotalInvitations value is greater than 100 then
   >   save in 100.csv else save in others.csv

   You will probably want the `os` package's [`Create`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Create) function to create a new file for writing or the [`OpenFile`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#OpenFile) function, the [`O_CREATE`, `O_WRONLY`, and `O_APPEND`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#O_WRONLY) file-open flags, and you can pass `0755` as the permission mode (or another set of octal permissions if you want to change access of a file).

   You can then use `csvWriter := csv.NewWriter(csvFile)` to wrap the resulting `io.Writer` (assuming there is no error opening the file).  From there, you can just write whatever information you require to the file as CSV records.  Don't forget to call `csvWriter.Flush` to flush the output buffer and `csvWriter.Error` to check whether there was an error flushing the output buffer.  Also don't forget to close the file you opened.

Comment: @Nancyme You should consider taking a look at the [Learning section of the documentation](https://golang.org/doc/#learning) and also [explore the core packages](https://golang.org/pkg/). You seem to not understand that the `Write` method of `*csv.Writer` only accepts `[]string`, not `int`. You had the right idea, but you need to determine what data to write to the file and how to convert that data to a slice of strings to do it.

Comment: like this  `TotalInvites := [][]string{{s.Guestlist[i].TotalInvitations}}`

Comment: @Nancyme You're not converting the integer to a `[][]string` object by doing that; you're creating a new `[][]string` object with an integer as the only value, which won't work because `int` is not a type that is compatible with `string`. Learn, don't just guess. We're here to help if you encounter trouble and need to ask a question, not to teach you the entire language; I linked resources for learning in my last comment on this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I am trying hard to learn the things but i can't learn the whole language in a single day and i want this ASAP so need some support, I have successfully able to compile & its working as desired with the edited answer, but i am still not sure if its just a workaround or we can modify it to something more professional, I will appreciate if you can take a look and modify accordingly, thanks and i appreciate your support

Comment: It's on the right track, but you're going beyond the scope of your original question. Please ask a new question if you need more help and good luck. :)

Comment: was the code perfect or we can write it more professionally?

Comment: its problem#2 i mentioned in the question

Comment: @Nancyme Do you agree Pavlo's solution as good one? In my opinion, you should follow that answer